# No changes have made but AWS 502 gateway error

Tags: amazon-web-services, gateway

I have a site running on AWS, the spec of free tier. It has been running almost more than 10 months without any trouble, but I found lately it has the 502 gateway, not be reached.

My question here is I haven't touched the settings or any, I suddenly got this. Wondered what caused it or what's happened. Is this a common issue? How can I avoid it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your infrastructure?

Comment: I have used the AWS free tier service, the ubuntu spec. I haven't set up any load balancers.

Comment: Can you confirm that the web server software (apache, nginx) that you use is still running? Also that you do not have a security group whitelist of specific IP addresses

Comment: I see. I am using nginx/ubuntu. A security group is running, elastic IP address is assigned to the EC. No load balancers are running. Route 53 is used for the domain which is from another provider.

Comment: Does the security group allow access to all hosts for http/https? Is nginx running?

Comment: It was not running so I rebooted it. Let me get the security group access. It is allowing all for http/https. And the site is https, http->https.

Comment: OK, can you access it from the server. I.e. curl https://localhost?

Comment: Http & https are set to 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0 in the inbound rules.

Comment: Add running `curl https://localhost` from your server?

Comment: It is running at the moment, but I found now and then it returns that gateway error. I tried to understand why this occurs.

Comment: Is it https://localhost or http://localhost? The http retunrns 'nginx' message, but https returns 'no matching'.